# Get RuleId from Coupon Code in checkout\cart\item\default.phtml

Tags: magento2, checkout, coupon-codes

I have overridden the **checkout\cart\item\default.phtml** in my theme.
**To get the 'used' coupon code** I've found below rules in other questions:

```
$getCoupon = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon');
$coupon_code = $getCoupon->getCouponCode();
```

This is working fine, **however I need the RuleId** so I can check whether the correct coupon code type is used.

In a class with DI I can resolve this with:

```
$ruleId = $this->coupon->loadByCode($coupon_code)->getRuleId();
// coupon => use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon;
```

There is no such block that I can import so I can have access to the getRuleId function?

**What is the correct manner to establish this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get **rule_id** by **coupon_code**

Try this to get the rule id using helper

In your helper

```
<?php                                                                 
namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Helper;                                   
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper               
{ 
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponFactory $couponFactory
 ) {
    $this->couponFactory = $couponFactory;
}
public function getItem($code = '')
{
    $code = 'XXXXXX'; //your coupon code which you've got on default.phtml
    $collect = $this->couponFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('code', $code);
    $couponId = array();
    foreach ($collect as $value) {
        $couponId = $value->getRuleId();
    }
    print_r($couponId);
}}
```

then in your default.phtml

call this and pass the coupon code as a params to the helper function as below

```
$this->helper('{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Helper\Data')->getItem($couponCode); //send the coupon code which you've got
```

Hope this helps :)