# How to display list of coupon code in product page in magento 2.2.7

Tags: coupon-codes, magento2.2.7

How to display list of coupon code in product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Add a helper on your custom module and path be like

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

then add the below code to get the coupon code collection

```
<?php                                                                 
namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Helper;                                   
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper               
{ 
  public function __construct(
   \Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponFactory $couponFactory
  ){
     $this->couponFactory = $couponFactory;
   }
  public function getCoupon()
  {
     $couponCollection = $this->couponFactory->create()->getCollection();
     return $couponCollection;
  }
}
```

then add catalog_product_view.xml in your custom module and path be like

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

then add the below code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="product_coupon" template="Vendor_Module::coupon.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

then add the phtml in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/coupon.phtml

then add the below code to the phtml file to get the coupon collection

```
<?php $coupon = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getCoupon();
foreach($coupon as $items)
{
  echo "Coupon Code :" . $items->getCode();
}
```

You'll get all the coupon code there and you can get any other attribute from this table **salesrule_coupon**

For more information refer this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264412/get-ruleid-from-coupon-code-in-checkout-cart-item-default-phtml/264439#264439)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @prathap. I want only available coupon code of current product not all.